# Comma below footer on Gatsby site

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a comma below my footer on a Gatsby site and I cannot find its source. It is at the end of the wrapper div with id "___gatsby". I have searched all component files and a bunch of other files to no avail. Going through all previous Git versions to find the change would be very burdensome at this point. Perhaps someone has an idea, based on the DOM structure below, where to best search for the comma?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: We can't debug images. Post a [mcve] please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

It turns out that a rogue character in gatsby-browser.js, in this case a comma after a closing tag, will be added in this way to the end of the #___gatsby div. In this case I overlooked the comma even through search because the comma was at the end of a long line of code and so did not appear visually in the search results list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the find & replace functionality (or even just find) of your IDE/text editor and use the following regular expression:

```
\s,|,\s,
```

Here you have a working example of that regex: https://regexr.com/6hogi

Comment: Thanks but I still can't find it. Going to ask the Gatsby community on GitHub if they have any idea.

Comment: As you wish, I personally think it's not necessary. It's not a Gatsby problem/issue but your implementation. You should be able to fix it by looking for all comma references It's inside the main `div` (`<div id="___gatsby"`) so start looking in the `Layout` and other global wrappers

Comment: The thing is, all components are rendered in the first child div, #gatsby-focus-wrapper. Then there is the #gatsby-announcer, which is empty; and THEN the comma appears as a direct child of #___gatsby. This is why, even though I have searched main.js and layout.js and all other components, it wouldn't make sense if the comma was there.